# PostgreSQL Allow to Invalid Group By

Tags: postgresql

I have two databases instances on Digital Ocean and both running on Postgresql 14.8.
Database queries and migrations applied by Python/Django.

Problem description with a sample query:

```sql
select 
    id, first_name, last_name
from users
group by id;
```

As far as I know this query should be invalid to execute, because group by clause should include all items in the select statement, except aggragated ones.

However, one of the database instances can execute this query, but other one can't.
I am not looking for the correct SQL query. I am trying to understand the problem.
I couldn't find where to look for this setting in database.

Extra:
I am connecting to databases by DataGrip. One of the connections showing a warning on the query as follows:

`Column '<table_name>.<column_name>' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

It means, DataGrip can read the settings and knows which connection is allowing to invalid group by query.

I am really confused on this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption

> group by clause should include all items in the select statement, except aggregated ones

is not correct. If you group by a primary key that grouping is effectively the same as grouping by all the columns and therefore a valid `GROUP BY`.

See

- [Why can I select all fields when grouping by primary key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158015/why-can-i-select-all-fields-when-grouping-by-primary-key-but-not-when-grouping-b) and
- [the postgres GROUP BY documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the primary key detail.
The table I am having the problem has been corrupted, and the ID has not registered as the primary key.